# SpringBoard failed to launch application with error : -3 & 0

Tags: ios7, xcode5

I've installed `Xcode 5.0.2`, Most of the Time, when I run my application in Simulator.
I'm getting Error, which is -

[image]

[image]

If any one could tell me, the `Cause of Error` and `How it can be resolved` .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally got answer,According to me I have found this-

Thanks for answering this question, but no one suggested me the `Cause of Error`.

```
It is known bug issue in Xcode 5.0.2
```

Cause of Error- Actually in Xcode 5.0.2, We've 4 Inch, 3.5 Inch and 64 Bit of simulator, So when we tried to change it, it cause the Error. For More details Refer [HERE](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-SW308)

I found this is the best solution to get rid the above error's (-3,0) .Thanks @user1547937 for suggesting for `Reset and Content and settings`.

```
1-Goto iOS Simulator 
2-Click Reset and Content and settings.
3-Clean Your Code (Shift+Cmd+K)
4-Build Your Code (Cmd+b)
5-Finally Run Your Code
```

Answer (score 16):

a) Goto Ios Simulator -> **Click Reset and Content and settings.**
   b) **Now clean, build and run your application.**
    I thing it will work.
   Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Stumbled upon this today. I fixed it by

- **a) running a clean (Product > Clean)**,
- **b) cleaning the build folder (holding the Option-Key while redoing the last step)** and
- **c) changing the simulated device** once.

Now everything runs smooth again.

Comment: Hi , i am getting this error frequently. Can u tell me the reason.

Comment: If you still receive this error it may help to reset your Simulator. It should be starting in the background when you get this error. Make the simulator the active application. In the "iOS-Simulator" menu you'll see an option to reset it.

I got it once and the steps above fixed it for me. I don't know the reason for this specific error.

Comment: Deleting the app on the simulator may help too btw. ;)

Comment: The important part to this question is the *reason* why it is happening.  I just set the iPhone Simulator directory's privs to read and write for all, and now I get a Springboard -3 error (-3 6 in the console).  Once we know *why* this is happening, we can try to do something about it.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Simulator and kill the current running instance of your app. It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Xcode `Version 5.0.1 (5A2053)`. Just resetting the simulator fixed it for me. Cleaning and rebuilding might be quite time consuming, so try just resetting first.

My order of operations (in order of likely effectiveness) when having build issues is:

1. Reset the simulator
2. Clean
3. Delete build directory (cmd-option-shift-k)
4. Restart Xcode
5. Quit Xcode, Delete `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`, restart Xcode
6. Quit Xcode, Delete `/var/folders/*` (you'll get some permissions errors, but that's ok), Delete `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`, Restart Xcode
7. Restart your machine, Delete `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and `/var/folders/*`, restart Xcode

All of these have solved my problems in the past.

Answer (score 0):

For me I just quit the simulator and fired it up again, and it started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to fix this issue in the following order,

- Quit the simulator and Run the project.
- Product - Clean and then Run the Project.
- Delete the application in the iOS Simulator and Run the project.
- Reset the settings of iOS Simulator and Run the project.
- Quit the Xcode, Open it again and Run the Project.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the error above with 0, when you try to run your application, 
All you need to do is make sure your Simulator is the active window, and then open up the menu pictured below and click “Reset Content and Settings".

[image]

Comment: thansk it does work . i think i have updated it in my answer.